# Looking for a regex matching start and end apostrophe only within between string in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I've below string need to be able dynamic extract the string Start and End with apostrophe:-

*"Expected 'TESMWQ, WEFSML REDA' to equal 'TESFSM FDSML F90 TDA'."*

The results:

1. TESMWQ, WEFSML REDA
2. ESFSM FDSML F90 TDA

How is the regular expression looks like

Answer (score 3):

This will search for a single `'`, then any number of characters (including new lines, thanks to the 3rd argument of `findall`: `re.S`), and finally another single `'`.

It returns a `list` of all the matches.

```
>>> import re
>>> string = r"Expected 'TESMWQ, WEFSML REDA' to equal 'TESFSM FDSML F90 TDA'."
>>> re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", string, re.S)
['TESMWQ, WEFSML REDA', 'TESFSM FDSML F90 TDA']
```

Note it does not account for escaped single quotes within the quoted strings.